# Prove that the balanced hull of a compact subset $K$ of a Hausdorff TVS $E$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space Hausdorff (over $\mathbb{C}$) and $K \subset E$ compact. I want to prove that: if $M$ is the balanced hull, that is, $M$ is smallest balanced set containing $K$, then $M$ is compact.

But I didn't have any idea how to proceed.

Remembering that: a subset $A$ of a vector space $E$ is said to be balanced if for every $x\in A $ and every $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, $|\lambda|\leq 1$, we have  $\lambda x \in A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Write $D$ for the set of complex numbers $z$ with $\lvert z\rvert \leq 1$. Then $M=DK$.

Comment: I can't see why this equality holds.

Comment: For instance, if $m \in M$, then why there exists $\lambda \in D$ and $k \in K$ such that $m=\lambda k$? And thus, $M \subset DK$.

Comment: The inclusion $DK \subset M$ I think holds because, since $M$ is balanced and  $$\lambda m \in M, \; \forall \; \lambda \in D, m \in K \subset M.$$

Comment: For the other inclusion, you only need to see that $DK$ is balanced. But this is pretty obvious, since $A$ is balanced iff $A=DA$ and $D=DD$.